# Say thank you in bootstrap modal

Tags: php, email, message, contacts

I have a contact form in bootstrap that sending by email is works great. 
But I want to say "thank you and will get back to you" in bootstrap modal AFTER successful send the message.

My question is that how can I put the code to show the message "thank you " in the bootstrap modal AFTER successful send the message where it said `@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);`

```
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user blue"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="Name" class="form-control" autofocus="autofocus" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope blue"></i></span>
                                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-phone blue"></i></span>
                                <input type="number" name="telephone" placeholder="Phone" class="form-control" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment blue"></i></span>
                                <textarea name="comments" rows="3" class="form-control" type="text" required></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info pull-right" >Email Form</a>
                        Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
                            <button type="reset" value="Reset" name="reset" class="btn">Reset <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"></span></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-container-784141" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">

                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                                ×
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">
                                Modal title
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            ...
                        </div>
                        <grammarly>
                            <div class="_9b5ef6-textarea_btn _9b5ef6-not_focused">
                                <div class="_9b5ef6-transform_wrap">
                                    <div class="_9b5ef6-status">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </grammarly>
                        <div class="modal-footer">

                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                                Close
                            </button> 
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Save changes
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
```

and

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "xxxt";

    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }



    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";

    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";





// create email headers

$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".

'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .

'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);




?>




<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: What's the question? To give you code? Ask us a specific and concise question where you describe with *relevant* code.

Comment: My question is that how can I put the code to show the message "thank you " in the bootstrap modal AFTER successful send the message where it said @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are going to show your thank you modal-dialog in your php code, so here's the code I made (based on your php code) :

```html
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['email'])) {



    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "xxxt";

    $email_subject = "Your email subject line";





    function died($error) {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";

        echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";

        echo $error."<br /><br />";

        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";

        die();

    }



    // validation expected data exists

    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||

        !isset($_POST['email']) ||

        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||

        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {

        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       

    }



    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required

    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required



    $error_message = "";

    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';

  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {

    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";

  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {

    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {

    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.<br />';

  }

  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {

    died($error_message);

  }

    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";



    function clean_string($string) {

      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");

      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);

    }
} else {
 ?>

 <!-- Modal Thank You -->
<div id="input_barang" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <!--<h4 class="modal-title">Input Jenis Barang</h4>-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
       
       Than You !

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

You did not close your first 'if' statement with '}' so I added the else statement on that first 'if' statement located above your clean_string function. Hope it helps, good luck!

Comment: yes, i have tried that this morning and it doesn't work at all is just stayed same blank page but not showing modal. any idea!